# What happens to the response sent by a lambda function back to the kinesis stream that triggers it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

In my architecture:

producer -> AWS Kinesis Stream -> lambda function -> MongoDB Atlas

What happens to the status code and data sent back from the lambda function to the kinesis trigger? Will the kinesis send it back to the producer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. See [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html#services-kinesis-errors) for details. The kinesis trigger reads the response from the lambda and performs actions depending on what has been defined. The producer is not automatically notified.

What you can do is to define a *On-failure destination* which is using a i.E. an SQS queue. The producer might listen on that queue and handle failures